# Using Worksheets. .Replace function for specific cell instead of entire column/row

Tags: vba, excel, replace

The following code works well for replacing a specific value in an entire column:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(MyColumnLetter).Replace _
what:=val_Old, Replacement:=val_New, lookat:=xlWhole, _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
```

However I only need to replace value in a specific cell (for example in cell "D9" as part of a vba loop) instead of the entire column or cell range.

Can anyone please suggest the required modification to the code above?

Thanks.

Comment: to replace only the value in D9 use `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D9").Replace _
what:=val_Old, Replacement:=val_New, lookat:=xlWhole, _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False` . You want to loop entire Column D ?

Comment: Like this `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, 4).Replace "hello", "good"` OR `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, 4).Replace "old value", "new value"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop through the entire Column D (until last row):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Replace_ColumnD()

Dim sht1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim lrow As Long
Dim val_new As String
Dim val_old As String


Set sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

For lrow = 1 To LastRow
     sht1.Cells(lrow, 4).Replace val_old, val_new
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace value in one cell A2:

```
Range("A2").Replace oldValue, newValue
```

Replace value in a range:

```
Range("A2:A10").Replace oldValue, newValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. It was very helpful indeed.
Finally the code looks like this:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow

MyRange = MyColumnLetter & i

If....condition met:
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(MyRange).Replace val_Old, val_New
End If

Next
```